# What is a 'nonexaggerated' word for egotistical?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Webster defines egotistical
: characterized by egotism : having, showing, or arising from an exaggerated sense of self-importance.  And other dictionaries add conceit and self-centered.

Webster defines ego:   the self especially as contrasted with another self or the world, and it's use associated with self esteem or self care.

What word in this family includes a healthy amount of ego, that is not exaggerated?  We all need to value self, and sometimes above others, but when it harms others unnecessarily, it become excessive on one extreme, or not enough on the other extreme.

I'm looking for a term that's on the ego spectrum from narcissistic (self consumed) to arrogant (puffed-up) to [the term I'm looking for] to self-negligent (lacking self-care) to co-dependent (consumed by the well being of others). Here's how I would use it in sentences:

His behavior was recognized as egotistical, but in fact was quite xxxxxxx.

We all need to be more xxxxxxx and less egotistical or oblivious to our own wellbeing.

His xxxxxxx behaviour was exactly what he needed for his own well being.

Comment: Did you look up any synonyms for egotistical in a thesaurus? Did any there seem to work or in what ways did none of them satisfy? Also your last two example sentences seem to put the word you're looking for on the opposite of a spectrum, whereas your description seems to specify in the same direction as egotistical but just not as much. eg are you look for the opposite of egotistical (like 'selfless') or just a weakened form (like 'confident' might be for 'arrogant')?

Comment: How about "self-assured"?

Comment: @Mitch - thanks for  your comment - please see the edit to my question with "spectrum."  So I'm not looking for the synonym or antonym, I'm looking for the word that represents the the middle of the spectrum, which includes a healthy or constructive dose of ego...not too little or not too much.

Comment: So you want an adjective that means "has healthy self-esteem"?

Comment: @nnnnnn esteem is self-worth...I'm thinking more about the balance of looking at one's welfare AND the welfare of others in a healthy balance.  So ego is the right root.

Comment: What do you mean by “one ask” and “second ask”? Do you mean “first/second question” or perhaps the two ends of a spectrum?

Comment: @Lawrence Spectrum.  A lot of my work is aimed at helping people recognize where on the Spectrum something is instead of trying to pigeon hole it or divide it.  We are rarely one thing or another all of the time...we slide up and down the Spectrum, and I'm trying to find the words/terms on the Spectrum egotistical is on.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Consider calling them “one extreme” and “other extreme” instead of “one/two ask”.

Comment: has a healthy ego

Comment: @Lambie - I so agree!  I'm getting too hung up on the psychology though...looking for the technical terms instead of the common ones...but maybe that's the key...to define 'healthy ego.'  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

(I've slightly reworded your first sentence.)

> His behavior was recognized as egotistical, but in fact it was just
> healthy **self-confidence**.
>
> We all need to be more **self-confident** and less egotistical or
> oblivious to our own wellbeing.
>
> His **self-confident** behaviour was exactly what he needed to learn for
> his own well being.

**self-confidence** (n.)

> Confidence in oneself and in one's powers and abilities [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-confident)

**self-confident** (adj.)

> Having confidence in one's abilities, qualities, and judgement;
> characterized by self-confidence. OED

---

> Studies show that a high level of **self-confidence** is related to high
> levels of overall **well-being** and happiness. It has also been
> connected to creativity, which is a quality that can enrich
> relationships in numerous ways. [S. Degges-White and C.
> Borzumato-Gainey; *Friends Forever*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Friends_Forever/UNsPRRq2Hv4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=self-confident%20well-being&pg=PA152&printsec=frontcover) (2011)

> You should be cautioned, however, to learn the difference between
> **Self-confidence**, which is based upon sound knowledge of what you know and what you can do, and **egotism**, which is only based  upon
> what you *wish* you knew or could do.  ...
>
> If you have **Self-confidence**
> those around you will discover this fact. Let them make the discovery.
> They will feel proud of their alterness in having made the discovery,
> and you will be free from the suspicion of **egotism.** [Napoleon
> Hill; *The Law of Success*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Law_of_Success/5aqPgpRauhUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=egotism%20self-confidence&pg=PA127&printsec=frontcover) (1928)

> **Self-Confidence versus Egotism**
>
> We have all met the man who "knows it
> all." How offensive he is whenever and wherever met...But he is
> eternally an unmitigated and unanimous nuisance.
>
> It might be supposed
> that the medical profession, from liberal education should be free and
> exempt from these social and business plagues. But it is not so. ...
>
> ...we are glad to claim for our people what many regard as a synonym,
> *i.e.*, **self-confidence**. Tho seldom recognized, there is a vast
> difference between **egotism** and **self-confidence.** we admit their
> kinship, but deny their identity...
>
> The **egotist** has done nothing, while the man of **self-confidence**
> is the life and hope of the profession. [*The Medical World*, Vol. 18,
> p.81](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Medical_World/mh0CAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=egotism%20self-confidence&pg=PA81&printsec=frontcover) (1900)

> If **egotism** be synonymous with **self-confidence**, every
> successful man is an egotist, for he dares to attempt what hundreds
> have failed to accomplish, and ventures to compete with real ability
> and skill. [Rev. A. T. Pierson; "Egotism versus Self-Knowledge", *Our Monthly*, Vol. 4, p.220](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Our_Monthly/KdEQAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=egotism%20self-confidence&pg=PA220&printsec=frontcover)  (1871)

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from interpretive words and trying to be more definitive.  Confidence is in the eye of the beholder, and what might seem like justified confidence to one person might be unjustified to another.  My focus is a word that belongs on a spectrum that has narcissism on one extreme (self-absorbed) and arrogant on the other extreme (considers themselves more knowledgeable than they are).  My self-confidence can be arrogant and narcissistic.

Comment: You're not going to get an objective term that doesn't depend on interpretation or judgment. Consider big-medium-small in sizes: what counts as medium depends on situation and opinion. Unless you have some sort of electronic device that measures self-opinion and plan to provide a reading from that.

Comment: OP wants a word on the "ego spectrum". It appears from the sample sentences that *others* are doing the judging.

Answer (score 0):

You might try "*dignified*".

> ([lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/dignified)) Having or showing a composed or serious manner that is worthy of respect.
> ‘she maintained a dignified silence’

However, here is more about this word.

> (SOED) **2** invested with dignity; exalted.
> **3** Marked by dignity; having self respect without haughtiness; stately.

- His behavior was recognized as egotistical, but in fact was quite *dignified*.
- We all need to be more *dignified* and less egotistical or oblivious to our own wellbeing.
- His *dignified*  behaviour was exactly what he needed to learn for his own well being. (*The phrasing is not ideal in this sentence; it should be reworked.*)

Answer (score 0):

> His behavior was recognizes as egotistical, but in fact was quite **normal**.

You should realise that adjectives modify nouns and that nouns usually have a default neutral meaning. Someone's behaviour is assumed to be normal unless otherwise stated or remarked upon.

Comment: Was recognizes?

Comment: interesting...so instead of trying to find a specific term, use a normative term, like less/more or reasonable/unreasonably, or justified/unjustified?

Answer (score 0):

I would think ***self-respectful*** could work in these contexts. Not being oblivious of one's well-being is about ***self-esteem***.

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-respect#:%7E:text=1%20%3A%20a%20proper%20respect%20for,one%27s%20own%20standing%20or%20position) defines *self-respectful* as:

> a proper respect for oneself as a human being

and gives *[self-regard](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-regard)* (which I quite like, but fringes more on the egotist side) as a synonym of *self-respect*.